# How to make an image a span's background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a console image, and I want to put a span element over it so that it looks like the console is putting out text. I've tried a few different ways of doing it, but none of them have worked like I hoped. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: You have to show some effort, including some code, before you'll get any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
<div class="console">
    <span>my text is written here</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.console {width:400px;height:300px;background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbF9b1wVlFVXLu-j4YvG9sb3521x09Nsbj65iBWpMA1chqM2RwsQ");background-size:cover;}
.console span {display:block;padding:70px;}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I haven't checked Stack Overflow in a while, so I didn't see it. Sorry.